# Oracle - Multi-line SQLs via JDBC - Apex SQL Workshop or SQL Plus

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Through my Java/Grails webapp, I'd like to have a form/program that allows the user to upload a SQL file (or paste the contents) and have it executed. Exactly like the SQL Workshop in Oracle Apex does. My ideal solution would be if I could embed the SQL Workshop that comes in Apex within my webapp.

I've seen the posts regarding multi-line SQL files.. they usually involve parsing for semi-colons, and I couldn't find one that seemed to properly handle that and declare-begin-end blocks and Oracle DDLs all at the same time. Plus, they all seem to try to re-invent what SQL Plus does. Being able to invoke SQL Plus would also great, but I'm not sure there's a way to do that cleanly through a web-app?

Questions: 
1) Is there anyway to "embed" the SQL Workshop that comes with Apex within my custom web-app? 
2) If not... Is there a "clean" way to invoke SQL Plus through a Grails/Java web-app? One that would also be platform independent?

Please feel free to provide any feedback... I'm new to web development so would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Do you have any say in what content is uploaded? i.e. what if you surround the input with a big `BEGIN..END;` block and just execute it as a single PL/SQL block? Obviously you'd have to disallow SQL*Plus commands and standalone SQL queries, but it would be useful for executing anonymous blocks, and for running inserts, updates and deletes.

Comment: Nope, I have no say.. Nor do I want to place restrictions on what is allowed, if that's part of what you meant. It would ideally allow everything SQL Plus allows. Correct me if I'm wrong, but... I think surrounding it by a begin-end would prevent DDL statements. Also... I want to also allow declare-begin-end anonymous blocks too... So surrounding it with another begin-end would introduce problems, I think. I even would like to allow a "mix" of anonymous blocks and "stand-alone" DDL/DML statements.